# RxJS combine multiple streams into one

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'm using NGRX and I want to get some values from the store, merge them into one and push to BE.

```
private enrichWith(event: TwoDimensionalCategory): Observable<any> {
    if (event.step || event.subCategory) {
      return Observable.merge(
        this.getCampaignId().first(),
        this.getCompanyIds().first(),
        this.getCampaignTitle().first(),
        this.getSectionCode().first(),
      );
    }
    return Observable.of({});
  }
```

I merge all streams from store

```
 private getCampaignId() {
    return this.store.select(getCampaignId).map(campaignId => {
      return { campaignId: campaignId };
    });
  }

  private getCampaignTitle() {
    return this.store.select(getCampaignTitle).map(campaignTitle => {
      return { campaignTitle: campaignTitle };
    });
  }
  private getSectionCode() {
    return this.store.select(getSectionCode).map(sectionCode => {
      return { sectionCode: sectionCode };
    });
  }

  private getCompanyIds() {
    return this.store.select(getCompanyIds).map(companyIds => {
      return { companyIds: companyIds };
    });
  }
```

Then I want to perform merge all over the returned value:

`return this.enrichWith(event)` //do something to merge all the items into one object.

I tried

```
this.enrichWith(event).mergeAll().flatMap(enrichedWithData => ...)
```

but get an error:

> TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected.

Comment: did you try a zip operartor?

Comment: Or the combineLatest operator? http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest

Comment: @AlexanderBondarenko zip will provide a sequence of arrays like [{field1:..}], [{field2:..}], [{field3:..}], [{field4:..}] cause I have 4 streams from store. But what I need is to get [{field1:..}, {field2:..}, {field3:..}, {field4:..}] or even better {field1:.., field2:.., field3:.., field4:..}

Comment: Found a solution:

return this.enrichWith(event).zip().combineAll().flatMap(enrichedWithData => ...)